# Dynamic list with JSON in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

I have a new Person form which have a table of objects like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed flip-content">
    <thead class="flip-content">
        <tr>
            <th width="20%">
                Tipo encabezado
            </th>
            <th width="20%">
                 Valor
            </th>
            <th width="10%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="ht : ${headersType}">
            <td th:text="${ht.headerType.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${ht.value}"></td>
            <td class="operations">
                <a class="delete" href="/profile/delete" th:href="@{/profile/delete/__${p.id}__}">
                    Borrar
                </a>
            </td>               
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This table corresponds to the following property of Person form

```
private Set<EntityHeader> headersType = new HashSet<EntityHeader>();
```

So, when I press New Header link I want to update this table with the new info without reloading the page. For now, I have this JSON method to do it

```
function addHeader(){

    var headerType = $('#idHeaderType').val(); 
    var valueHeader = $('#valueHeaderType').val(); 
    var json = {"headerType.id" : headerType,"value" : valueHeader};  
    $.ajax({
        url: "addHeader.json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "idHeader="+headerType+"&valueHeader="+valueHeader,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(){

        },
        error:function(){

        }


    });
}
```

This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "person/addHeader.json", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers ="Accept=application/json")
    public String addHeader(@RequestParam(value = "idHeader") String idHeader,
            @RequestParam(value = "valueHeader") String valueHeader, @ModelAttribute("person") PersonForm personForm,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        EntityHeader eh = new EntityHeader();
        eh.setHeaderType((HeaderType) basicServ.findById(Long.parseLong(idHeader), HeaderType.class));
        eh.setValue(valueHeader);
        personForm.getHeadersType().add(eh);
        model.addAttribute("person", personForm);


        return "person/new";

    }
```

I'm trying to retrieve PersonForm from model and update the list with new values. But when I try to save it, headersType in PersonForm is empty and of course the table doesn't show the added headers.

**EDIT**: I post a provisional solution but I prefer do it with JSON

Answer (score 0):

I found a provisional solution to do this. I made all code with JQuery and append rows with hidden fields, I prefer a JSON solution, but at the moment...

**addHeader**

```
function addHeader(){

    var count = 0;

    var headerType = $('#idHeaderType').val();
    var headerTypeValue = $("#idHeaderType option:selected").text();
    var valueHeader = $('#valueHeaderType').val(); 

    var nuevoCount = count +1;

    $('#cuerpoTabla').append("<tr id='encabezado_"+nuevoCount+"'><td>"+headerTypeValue+"<input type='hidden' name='headersType["+count+"].headerType.id' id=headersType["+count+"].headerType.id' value='"+headerType+"'/></td><td>"+valueHeader+"<input type='hidden' name='headersType["+count+"].value' id=headersType["+count+"].value' value='"+valueHeader+"'/></td></tr>");
}
```

And in personForm I change `Set<EntityHeader>` for a simple array `EntityHeader[]`

**Still waiting for another answers**